# SiteFinity Forms- Notify Submitter when response is edited?

Tags: webforms, sitefinity

I have a sitefinity form set to send a copy of the form response (submission) to the submitters entered email address.

I also have a notification email setup with a staff members email address to notify them when a form is submitted.

By default, staff can "edit" a form, and the notification email is sent, again, to the staff member. However, I want the "edited" information sent to the original sender, not the staff member. Kind of "We've completed your item" response.

The notification area does not accept dynamic values- is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a nice feature request.

Your best bet is to subscribe to **IFormEntryUpdatedEvent** event and manually send the email to the user.

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-forms-events#iformentryupdatedevent